# Stripe payment with apple pay token using React native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, create-react-native-app

I have installed package react-native-payments in react native project, and i have token from that response, using that token i wants to do payment with stripe, is that any api available? to use apple pay token with stripe.

basically we have to check with token which will get from apple pay and then can able to pass in strip payment api method, Is any thing available from api side ?

Answer (score 2):

The react-native-payments library has a Stripe-specific plugin that you can use:

https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments/tree/master/packages/react-native-payments-addon-stripe

As documented, this plugin will allow you to receive Stripe-chargeable tokens as part of the [PaymentResponse](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments#processing-payments).

Once you have the Stripe Token you'll need to send it to you server where you can save it to a Stripe Customer to make charges with. If the token you get back from the library has a `tok_` prefix that means that it's a legacy Token, so you'd likely want to convert that to the newer PaymentMethods API. To do this you would create a new PaymentMethod and pass in `card: { token: "tok_xyz" }`. From there you can save the newly created PaymentMethod (will have a `pm_` prefix) to a Stripe Customer:

- Create a Stripe Customer: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create
- Save the PaymentMethod: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach

You can then use the Customer/PaymentMethod duo to process payments using all of Stripe's APIs.

Comment: It's not possible with react-native-payments package? We don't want to change package.

Comment: It's an add-on to the react-native-payments package. So I believe you would need both. If you already have react-native-payments installed you can follow the guide here to install the Stripe add-on: https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments/tree/master/packages/react-native-payments-addon-stripe#installation